# Total page count for pdf coming incorrect IE

Tags: java, itext

I have been using iText library to dynamically create PDF from data stored in the db. I used the getNumberOfPages() method of PDFReader class to get the total page count. I am displaying page numbering as 1 of 7...2 of 7...7 of 7 in the footer. This numbering is coming correctly in Firefox or chrome but when I open the pdf more than once in IE, the total page count increases by 1 i.e., if actual total pages are 7, it comes to be as 8. Is it a browser cache issue? And if it is, is there any permanent fix for it?

Comment: There is a difference between the number of pages and the page number of the last page. Some pages can be numbered in roman or with different offset. You should provide more context.

Comment: Please show us the code you are using to create the PDF. The behavior you describe is impossible: a PDF that is created on the server-side can not render 7 in one browser and 8 in another browser. Hence there must be something very particular to your code that creates a *different* PDF for MSIE when compared to a PDF created for Firefox or Chrome.